# ValidationException: Must have at least one non-optional hash key condition in WHERE clause when using ORDER BY clause

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have this query where I fetch all messages based on these conditions:

```
SELECT id, message, created, sender_company_id, receiver_company_id, read_msg, receiver_user_id, receiver_user_name, 
        sender_user_name, sender_user_id, sender_company_name, receiver_company_name
       FROM "messages"."sender_company_id-created-index"
       WHERE (sender_company_id = 435634652 AND sender_user_id = 186) 
       OR (receiver_company_id = 435634652 AND receiver_user_id = 186)  // if I remove this condition it works
       ORDER BY created ASC, sender_company_id ASC
```

Here are the indexes I have created with sorting keys so that I can use ORDER BY:

[image]

And as you can see in the query I am using "sender_company_id-created-index":

```
...FROM "messages"."sender_company_id-created-index"
```

If I try to run the query with only the first condition, it works but that's not what I want to do, I want both conditions to be in the query.

Here is the error it throws when I try to run it in the AWS console:

**ValidationException: Must have at least one non-optional hash key condition in WHERE clause when using ORDER BY clause.**

It doesnt make sense because I am actually using both, optional and non-optional keys as conditions. I cant see what am I doing wrong here, can someone help?

Comment: This relates to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72732144/why-querying-with-order-by-fails-in-dynamodb) asked by the same OP.

Answer (score 0):

To do both conditions would be a join. DynamoDB does not support joins like this. You can use one index OR the other, but not both at the same time.

I'd suggest you do two queries here (one against each index) and join the results on the client side.

Comment: but does that mean all conditions that include an OR are joins and do not work in dynamodb?

Comment: I suggest you review the vanilla DynamoDB API. That’s what dynamo can do. Then you can decide to use PartiQL as another way to access that functionality. Starting with PartiQL gives you all this expressive power that isn’t supported and can confuse people.